# Can I visit the UK to see my husband if my settlement (spouse) visa is still in processing?

Tags: visas, uk

I'm a Canadian citizen and recently got married in Canada to a British man. I've applied for the settlement visa and we're awaiting a decision. I paid a fee to keep my passport while the application is being processed.

I want to go to the UK and spend the holidays with my husband. As a Canadian passport holder I am allowed to be there for 6 months at a time.

I have heard that, if you have already applied for a Settlement/Spouse Visa, it is unwise for a spouse to come to stay before it has been granted as it could jeopardise the application.

Will visiting him jeopardise our application? Will an Immigration Officer deny my entry if I tell them our situation as we've not got a decision yet?

Comment: Do you mean a family visa? If you were applying for settlement, you would have already lived in the UK with your partner for five years.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments. Putting on hold.